# Uploading photos from website to android app

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, jsoup

I'm trying to retrieve photos from a website using AsyncTask, ListView and Jsoup into my android app. Having some difficulties between the 2 classes (one who extends Activity and the other who extends AsyncTask) Here is my Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

       private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
     listView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listview); 
     list = new ArrayList();
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new LoadImages(list, adapter).execute();

}
```

And this is the AsyncTask class:

```
public class LoadImages extends AsyncTask {

private ArrayAdapter adapter;
```

private ArrayList list;

```
public LoadImages(ArrayList list, Adapter adapter)
{
    this.list = list;
    this.adapter = (ArrayAdapter) adapter;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Elements divs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(divs);
     for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element div : divs)
     {   
        list.add(div);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    Document doc = null;

    try {


    doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://mongol.co.il/").get();
    Elements divs =((Elements) doc).select("img[src$=.jpg]");


     } catch (IOException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;



}
```

}

Comment: The `list` is the data you want to display in your `ListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MainActivity.java should be

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        list = new ArrayList();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new LoadImages(list, adapter).execute();
    }
}
```

Your AsyncTask class shoud be

```
public class LoadImages extends AsyncTask
{
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList list;

    public LoadImages(ArrayList list, Adapter adapter)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Elements divs)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for ( org.jsoup.nodes.Element div : divs )
        {
            list.add(div);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        Document doc = null;
        try
        {
            doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://mongol.co.il/").get();
            return  ((Elements) doc).select("img[src$=.jpg]");
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note :** There is ClassCastExcception in the line `return ((Elements) doc).select("img[src$=.jpg]");`. The solution is only to update the listview from Background thread not for the question edited with logcat error (*See below Comments for clarification*).

Comment: How can I pass the "list" from one class to another?

Comment: @Avi2107 Kindly revert back your last edit. so other users will find the question exactly. you said that the app is crashing. so i asked you update the question with error log

Comment: the error is at the line 42 in LoadImages.java. Error in converting between different datatypes. Which is the line 42?

Comment: doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://mongol.co.il/").get();   This is line 42 at LoadImages.java

Comment: The problem is with this line ((Elements) doc).select("img[src$=.jpg]"); because we are trying to convert Document to the data type Elements. you can try clearing this by yourself or you can open a new question with the error. Because i don't know jsoup and the discussion is going long.

Answer (score 0):

Try do this on your imageviewHolder of adapter:

```
Connect.loadBitmap( 0, "http://www.saudeanimal.com.br/imagens/suricate06.jpg",
                new BitmapLoadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadListener( int id, Bitmap bitmap ) {
                        if( bitmap != null ) {
                            tableBean.setImg( bitmap );
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                } );
```